# es6 arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would test this in browser

```
let foo = () => ({ bar: 2 })
```

But accidentally typed

```
let foo = () => { bar: 2}
```

Why didn't throw an error?

Comment: Because this is correct syntax

Comment: What does this have to do with scope?

Comment: ``let foo = () => { bar: 2}`` - "bar" is a label. So if you call this function it will return "undefunied"

Comment: @lomboboo thx, but undefined? doesn't bar:2 return 2

Comment: @lomboboo sorry, because it didn't return

Comment: @deceze my bad I thought something wrong with scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, `bar` is a label. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

"`2`" is a valid statement in itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Τhis is the basic syntax:**

```
() => { statements }
```

**And the advanced:**

```
// Parenthesize the body of function to return an object literal expression:
params => ({foo: bar})
```

[MDN Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

The two syntax are correct but they don't define the same function.

```
function foo1() {
  return {bar: 2};
}

function foo2() {
  bar: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what bar is. If its a label, that would the key of the object.
But that syntax wont work, if it was a variable.

Some additional syntaxes for the curious mind is shown below:-

```
let foo = () => ({ bar: 2}); //works. object is returned
//let foo = () => ({ 'bar': 2}); //works. object is returned

//let foo = () => { let bar = 2; return bar; }; //works
//let foo = (() => { let bar = 2; return bar; }); //works
//let foo = (() => { let bar = 2; return bar}); //works

//let foo = () => ({ let bar = 2; return bar; }); //WONT work
//let foo = (p1=3) => p1 ; //works
let foo = () => 1; //works

console.log(foo());
```